# Opinión personal o técnica

Tags: discusión

Desde hace un tiempo vengo viendo preguntas en las que el OP consulta sobre dos escenarios, o como debería ser esto o aquello. Pongamos un ejemplo más claro:

[¿Tiene sentido una operación exist en un api rest?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/128773/tiene-sentido-una-operaci%C3%B3n-exist-en-un-api-rest)

Por ejemplo en esta entrada, consulta sobre dos maneras de ejecutar un proceso, ahora bien ¿donde está el límite la respuesta para que sea "basada en opiniones personales"?

Me refiero, vengo viendo desde hace tiempo que se van cerrando preguntas o se informa al usuario que su consulta no es correcta por que se generaría debate con dicha consulta, pero ¿es realmente basada una respuesta en opiniones personales si se argumentan los resultados en base al rendimiento?.

En el caso de la consulta de este usuario, el rendimiento y tiempos de ejecución pueden variar en función de la manera que use de las dos que propone, ¿por que la respuesta estaría basada en opiniones personales?, los aspectos técnicos son los que son, y no es una opinión personal, esto tardará X tiempo en ejecutarse en Y máquina, y no hay opinión que lo rebata, es algo técnico.

Lo siento si soy muy pesado con este tipo de consultas, el motivo es simple: ofrecer una mejor experiencia a los usuarios en SOes, ya que muchas veces se cierran consultas que en mi opinión, están lejos de generar un debate si hablamos y argumentamos de manera "profesional o técnica".

Saludos,

Comment: En mi opinión, el ejemplo que muestras es un poco malo ya que la primera línea de la pregunta dice: `Recientemente ha surgido un debate en el grupo de trabajo al que estoy dedicado`. Ahí ya está indicando que es algo que genera debate porque hay diferentes opiniones, y aquí eso es motivo de cierre.

Comment: Es interpretable y cuestionable, pero puede que la respuesta sea exacta. Ellos pueden tener diferentes opiniones en base a X fundamentos, pero si hacemos un benchmark de ambos escenarios el resultado será exacto indiferentemente de las opiniones (si el usuario consultase implícitamente que necesita consumir la menor memoria posible por ejemplo. No obstante, me quedo con la respuesta de lois6b, siendo el autor el que tenga que esclarecer cual es el objetivo, pudiendo convertir la misma pregunta que podría parecer un debate en una solución concreta. En este caso, la consulta no es concreta.

Comment: Correcto @jonilgz, el que responde no sabe que es lo que busca el OP, asi que es el mismo OP el que tiene que aclarar en la pregunta lo suficiente para que haya una sola respuesta buena, y no que se genere un debate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Muchas veces un cierre de este tipo es por la redacción de la pregunta en sí.

Quiero decir que *"¿Cuál de las dos soluciones creéis que sería la más adecuada?"* es totalmente subjetiva. *"Creéis"* y *"la más adecuada"* son términos personales.

Cambiando la formulación de la pregunta, puede que el cierre no aplique.

Sin embargo parece que ambas opciones pueden ser válidas y simplemente es un cambio de estrategia.

No pide nada objetivo como tiempo de ejecución. Es, en mi opinión, una pregunta para que la gente discuta cuál debe elegir, donde cada uno puede dar *sus* motivos, sin basarse en una medida cuantitativa.

---

Además, no podemos supeditar una pregunta en función de las respuestas que puedan darse.

Hay casos de malisimas preguntas con grandísimas respuestas. No es un todo. Si la pregunta está mal, se cierra tenga o no tenga esa maravillosa respuesta.

Incluso las respuestas técnicas , como puedan darse en esta pregunta, pueden seguir siendo de opinión:

Imagina una situación hipotética:

- Una respuesta es que una de las soluciones da muy poco tiempo de ejecución pero mucha memoria usada.
- Otra respuesta explica cómo la otra solución da mucho mas tiempo de ejecución pero apenas usa memoria.

Sigue siendo subjetivo el valorar qué es mejor y por eso el autor ha de proveer qué quiere para su solución.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo, no obstante creo que se podría ayudar a los usuarios a dar más información. En base al buen ejemplo que comentas, consultarle si para la pregunta busca tiempo de ejecución o memoria en vez de directamente comentarle que no cumple con los requisitos para la pregunta por que podría generar debate. Muchas veces la gente pregunta "que es mejor", sin caer en que tiene que dar más detalles (falta de experiencia), ¿que es mejor para que?, tiempo de ejecución, consumo de memoria, conseguir un código más útil y genérico...

Comment: @jonilgz Para eso hay una solución muy fácil. Preguntar que es lo que está mal en tu pregunta. A parte de la página de `How To Ask` que es la página 'guía' para saber cómo preguntar.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/129627/xampp-no-me-funciona ¿Basada en opiniones?, es un error de Visual C++ redistributable...